# Annotation to avoid warnings in not used render attributes

Tags: java, json, jackson, vert.x

I´m using a java pojo to be rendered as json using Json.encode(instance).

The problem is, that because those attributes only are used for render propose my IDE is warning me that those final attributes never been used and does not contains any get() method.

Any idea if I can add a json annotation to tell me IDE that those attributes are mean to be used only for render propose?

By the way, I´m looking for an alternative solution to `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`

Regards.

Comment: Why not use @SuppressWarnings("unused") ?

Comment: I was looking for a solution a little more descriptive explaining why. As a last resource I will use this aproach

Comment: To define that a property is read only or write only you can use @JsonProperty(access=X). But I don't think that will remove the IDE warnings.